# How to exclude/whitelist certain websites only for certain filter lists in uBlock Origin?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web-filtering, ublock-origin, ublock

In addition to various filter lists for blocking ads, I also use a filter list for blocking cookie messages.

Some websites do not work properly because of this cookie blocking filter list.

Now I want to disable only the cookie message blocking filter list for these sites, not the ad blocking filter lists.

How can I achieve this?